# get all attributes of an overriden property

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

Take for example the below sample code:

```
    public class TestMultipleAttributesAttribute : AttributeWithPriority
    {
        public string HelpMessage { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student


    {
        [TestMultipleAttributes(HelpMessage = "Student")]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    }

    public class SpecificStudent : Student
    {
        [TestMultipleAttributes(Priority = 100, HelpMessage = "SpecificStudent")]
        public override string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there any way by reflection how I can get both the two instances of the `TestMultipleAttributes` for the same overriden property?

I tried the below code:

```
   [Test]
    public void testMultipleAttribs()
    {
        var property = typeof(SpecificStudent).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Name");

        var attribList = property.Attributes; //returns none
        var customAttribs = property.CustomAttributes.ToList(); //returns 1
        var customAttribs2 = property.GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true);// returns 1
        int k = 5;

    }
```

One solution that came in mind is to find the `property.DeclaringType`, and repeating the process , and get the attributes for it.  However, I don't find it an elegant way to do this and was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You have only one attribute named `TestMultipleAttributes` and you overwrote it.The attribute have more than one property (`Priority` and `HelpMessage`) its working correctly.

You can create more "really" attributes like so `StudentAttribute` and `SpecificStudentAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know...this is relatively elegant (though I'm sure I'm missing at least one special case). It should enumerate all the custom attributes on an overridden or virtual property in the inheritance chain in nearest-first order:

```
public static IEnumerable<Attribute>  AllAttributes( PropertyInfo pi )
{
  if ( pi != null )
  {
    // enumerate all the attributes on this property
    foreach ( object o in pi.GetCustomAttributes( false ) )
    {
      yield return (Attribute) o ;
    }

    PropertyInfo parentProperty = FindNearestAncestorProperty(pi) ;
    foreach( Attribute attr in AllAttributesRecursive(parentProperty) )
    {
      yield return attr ;
    }

  }

}

private static PropertyInfo FindNearestAncestorProperty( PropertyInfo property )
{
  if ( property == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("property") ;
  if ( property.DeclaringType == null ) throw new InvalidOperationException("all properties must belong to a type");

  // get the property's nearest "ancestor" property
  const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
                           | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic
                           | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance
                           ;
  Type         t        = property.DeclaringType.BaseType ;
  PropertyInfo ancestor = null ;

  while ( t != null && ancestor == null )
  {
    ancestor = t.GetProperty(property.Name,flags) ;
    t        = t.BaseType ;
  } ;

  return ancestor ;
}
```